Permutation groups without global fixed point where every element has a fixed point
I am looking for examples (or interesting statements) of finite permutation groups $G\leq \operatorname{Sym}(n)$ with the following two properties:

every element $g$ of $G$ has a fixed point, i.e., there is some $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ with $g(i)=i$ and
there is no global fixed point, i.e., there is no $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ such that $g(i)=i$ holds for all $g\in G$.

I already know that such groups exist since the subgroup $G=\langle g,f\rangle$ of $S_{21}$ generated by the two elements

$g=(1\,2\,3)(6\,7\,8)(9\,10\,11)(13\,14\,15)(16\,17\,18)(19\,20\,21)$ and
$f=(2\,5)(3\,4)(6\,7)(8\,9)(12\,13)(14\,16)(15\,19)(17\,21)$

has properties (1) and (2). However, I would like to have a simpler example and a better understanding of such groups. Any insight you can provide will be appreciated :)

How about ${(1 2)(3 4), (3 4)(5 6)}$?

Thank you, that works :) Unfortunately, this means I want stronger properties for G than I originally claimed. I will post a new Question once I figured out what I need.

It is probably worth mentioning that there is no transitive action with this property. This follows from Burnside's lemma: The number of orbits of $G$ on $[n]$ is $\tfrac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} #(\text{Fix}(g))$. For $g=e$, the number of fixed points is $n>1$ so, if you impose that $ #(\text{Fix}(g)) \geq 1$ for all $g$, then the average must be $>1$ and the action isn't transitive.

It is easier to understand what is going on conceptually with examples if you instead start with an abstract group $G$ and take an action of $G$ on some set.  For instance, suppose $G$ is any non-cyclic group, and let $A$ be the set of all cosets of proper subgroups of $G$.  Then $G$ acts on $A$ by translation.  Every element of $G$ fixes some element of $A$, namely the cyclic subgroup that it generates.  But no element of $A$ is fixed by all of $G$, since we restricted to proper subgroups of $G$ in the definition of $A$.
For another similar example, suppose $G$ is a group with trivial center, and let $G$ act on $G\setminus\{1\}$ by conjugation.  Every element of $G$ fixes some point (namely itself, or everything if your element is $1$).  However, no point is fixed by all of $G$, since the center of $G$ is trivial.
(If you take the second example with $G=S_3$, this gives the permutation group in $S_5$ generated by $(2\ 3)(4\ 5)$ and $(1\ 2\ 3)$ (here $1,2,3$ are the $2$-cycles in $S_3$ and $4,5$ are the $3$-cycles).  This can be shown to be the smallest possible degree of such a permutation group.)

Here is an alternative approach; like Eric we'll start with an abstract group $G$ first. Every action of $G$ on a set $X$ decomposes uniquely (up to reordering) into a disjoint union of orbits
$$X \cong \bigsqcup_i G/H_i$$
where every orbit is isomorphic as a $G$-set to the left action on $G/H_i$ for some subgroup $H_i$ (namely the stabilizer of some point in the orbit). This action has no global fixed points iff no stabilizer $H_i$ is all of $G$. So to satisfy the condition on global fixed points it suffices to restrict our attention to disjoint unions of quotients by proper subgroups.
Next we need a criterion for when an element $g \in G$ fixes a point in $G/H_i$. This says that $g g' H_i = g' H_i$ for some $g' \in G$, or equivalently that $g \in g' H_i g'^{-1}$, so the condition is that $g$ lies in some conjugate of $H_i$ (which makes sense since these are exactly the stabilizers all the points in $G/H_i$). So, in order for every element to have a fixed point, it is necessary and sufficient to choose the $H_i$ to be a collection of subgroups $\{ H_i \}$ of $G$ such that every $g \in G$ lies in some conjugate of some subgroup $H_i$, or equivalently such that every conjugacy class intersects some $H_i$.
An easy way to do this is to choose the $H_i$ to consist of all (nontrivial) cyclic subgroups of $G$; this gives Eric's first example. Eric's second example amounts to choosing the $H_i$ to consist of all (nontrivial) centralizers.
Finally we need to say something about when a group action is faithful. The kernel of $G$ acting on $G/H_i$ consists of the intersection $\cap_g gH_ig^{-1}$ of the conjugates of the $H_i$. So the condition is that the intersection of all these kernels over all $i$ is trivial. This together with the previous two comments abstractly characterizes all examples.
